# Sitecore multilist field data source from uCommerce category

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, umbraco-ucommerce

We have a Sitecore template on to which we want to put a Multilist field that allows a content editor to pick the top N products from uCommerce to relating to a page using this template. I have looked into using a Custom Data Template Field Source (http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/09/Sitecore-7-Custom-Classes-as-Data-Template-Field-Sources.aspx) and using the uCommerce APIs I can match the page name (which is the Category) to the Category in uCommerce.

I can then bring back the Products for the editor to pick from, however the last part I can't seem to do is convert these into Sitecore Items as that is the return type needed for the data source.

I guess there are 2 questions:

1. Is there a better (less flaky) way to get the products for the multilist based on category (dynamically)
2. How do you convert the uCommerce Product entities to Sitecore Items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uCommerce products exist in the Sitecore content tree as sitecore items which you can access and you could set the datasource of a multilist to that section of the content tree.

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, it looks like I was overcomplicating the problem. I have sorted it using a XPath Query to the Parent category in uCommerce filtering on a content template to restrict it to the correct products per category. Thanks